# Tertiary regression trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn, r

Is there a prepackaged python or R set of functions which have ternary (three branches) decision trees?

All of the out of the boxes I can find are for binary decision trees.

A wiki can be found [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_tree).

Comment: How would this work? [Decision tree learning algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning) work with boolean conditions which split the instances into two subsets (the condition is either true or false). To the best of my knowledge there is no learning algorithm which produces a ternary tree structure.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12187/232706